# Details of Nokia Music audio track, on Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7

When using Nokia Music, or any other audio streaming app on Windows Phone, is there any way of detecting what track is being played, like you would be able to with a normal audio file being played locally (through the Music+Video Hub), via the MediaPlayer object?

Comment: check nokia developer site - http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Category:Nokia_Music_API

Answer (score -1):

> any other audio streaming app on Windows Phone

You definitely can do it with [my audio streaming app](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/skyfm/dbdac8ef-03d0-4986-bd05-edb433c5aace). While it plays something in background, press a volume up or down button, and you'll see the artist & title of the song being played:

[image]

Comment: I think he means in the context of c# not through the UI.

Comment: @Colin, if he's able to query some mysterious "MediaPlayer object" (that's not part of the SDK, it must be some 3-rd party wrapper around MediaHistory.NowPlaying API) for the currently playing track, then he'll get what my app plays. The system "Music + Video" app does.

Comment: Thanks radoslaf, Colin and Soonts for your quick feedback! I am currently using the "Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.MediaPlayer" object to get the currently local playing track; I apparently am not able to use this object to detect streaming media, such as Nokia Music; is this is however possible using the "MediaHistory.NowPlaying" API? Thanks a ton in advance!

Comment: Hmm.. It seems I was wrong. I didn't know XNA has some unique methods to query the media player - I only developed for WP7's Silverlight. Anyway, you could also try the 3-rd way to query the data you need - try reading `BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Track` property.

Comment: Thanks again @Soonts! I tried using the `BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Track` property as well as the `MediaHistory.Instance.NowPlaying` property and neither one was able to detect a song playing when playing a track via Nokia Music. Both instances don't even show a player state of "Playing", even though music / track data shows up just like any other local music file, within the Universal Volume Control (UVC), and playback can be controlled in a similar fashion through the UVC. Doesn't make much sense; what other class might Nokia Music be using to play the audio?